# Why does this attempt to create a PivotTable (Excel Interop) fail?

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, excel-interop

Based on code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460922/how-to-add-an-excel-listobject-to-a-given-worksheet-in-c), I'm trying to create a Pivot Table like so:

```
var range = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[6, 1],
                           _xlSheet.Cells[6, _grandTotalsColumn]];
ListObject tbl = WriteToExcelTable(_xlSheet, "tbl", "A6");
var pch = _xlBook.PivotCaches();

pch.Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, "Produce Usage by Month!A6:F94")
    .CreatePivotTable(tbl, "PivTab1", Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
. . .

public ListObject WriteToExcelTable(Worksheet WSheet, string TableName, string CellStr = "A1", bool ClearSheetContent = false)
{
    Range range;

    if (ClearSheetContent)
        WSheet.Cells.ClearContents();  // clear sheet content

    // get upper left corner of range defined by CellStr
    range = (Range)WSheet.get_Range(CellStr).Cells[1, 1];   

    // Write table to range [ - don't have the helperfunc code commented this out ]
    //HelperFunc.WriteTableToExcelSheet(WSheet, this._tbl, range.Address);

    // derive range for table, +1 row for table header
    // [doesn't compile, so commented out] rang
    //range.get_Resize(this.RowCount + 1, this.ColumnCount);
    range = range.get_Resize(102, 5); // faking it to see what happens

    // add ListObject to sheet
    ListObject tbl = WSheet.ListObjects.AddEx(
        XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange,
        range,
        XlListObjectHasHeaders: XlYesNoGuess.xlYes);

    // set name of excel table
    tbl.Name = TableName;

    // return excel table (ListObject)
    return tbl;
}
```

...but it crashes on this line:

```
pch.Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, "Produce Usage by Month!A6:F94")
                .CreatePivotTable(tbl, "PivTab1", Type.Missing,   
Type.Missing);
```

...with:

```
System.ArgumentException was caught
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
  Source=""
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(Object TableDestination, Object TableName, Object ReadData, Object DefaultVersion)
       at ReportRunner.ProduceUsage.ProduceUsageRpt.AddPivotTable() in c:\Projects\ReportRunner\ReportRunner\ProduceUsage\ProduceUsageRpt.cs:line 3312
       at ReportRunner.ProduceUsage.ProduceUsageRpt.GenerateProduceUsageRpt() in c:\Projects\ReportRunner\ReportRunner\ProduceUsage\ProduceUsageRpt.cs:line 180
  InnerException:
```

What is wrong with my approach? Note that I had to comment out two lines from the borrowed method (WriteToExcelTable()) because they wouldn't compile for me.

### UPDATE

I also tried this alternative:

```
private void AddPivotTable()
{
    int rowIdx = 42; // try 42 for now; adjust as/if necessary
    var pch = _xlBook.PivotCaches();
    pch.Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, "PivotData!A6:D" + rowIdx)
        .CreatePivotTable(_xlSheet.Cells[6, 1], "PivTab1", Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    . . .
```

...which crashed on the last line shown with:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was caught
  HelpLink=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\1033\XLMAIN11.CHM
  HResult=-2146827284
  Message=Cannot open PivotTable source file 'C:\Users\cshannon\Documents\PivotData'.
  Source=Microsoft Office Excel
  ErrorCode=-2146827284
  StackTrace:
       at System.Dynamic.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, UInt32 argErr, String message)
       at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject , Object , String , Object , Object )
       at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
       at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , PivotCache , Object , String , Object , Object )
       at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
       at ReportRunner.ProduceUsage.ProduceUsageRpt.AddPivotTable() in c:\Projects\ReportRunner\ReportRunner\ProduceUsage\ProduceUsageRpt.cs:line 3172
       at ReportRunner.ProduceUsage.ProduceUsageRpt.GenerateProduceUsageRpt() in c:\Projects\ReportRunner\ReportRunner\ProduceUsage\ProduceUsageRpt.cs:line 180
  InnerException:
```

### UPDATE 2

Even after removing the "PivotData!", which apparently refers to a file named that from which to read data, so that the line is now:

```
pch.Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, "A6:D" + rowIdx)
```

...it still crashes, now with:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was caught
  HelpLink=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\1033\XLMAIN11.CHM
  HResult=-2146827284
  Message=Cannot change part of a merged cell.
  Source=Microsoft Office Excel
  ErrorCode=-2146827284
  StackTrace:
       at System.Dynamic.ComRuntimeHelpers.CheckThrowException(Int32 hresult, ExcepInfo& excepInfo, UInt32 argErr, String message)
       at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , ComObject , Object , String , Object , Object )
       at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
       at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , PivotCache , Object , String , Object , Object )
       at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
       at ReportRunner.ProduceUsage.ProduceUsageRpt.AddPivotTable() in c:\Projects\ReportRunner\ReportRunner\ProduceUsage\ProduceUsageRpt.cs:line 3174
       at ReportRunner.ProduceUsage.ProduceUsageRpt.GenerateProduceUsageRpt() in c:\Projects\ReportRunner\ReportRunner\ProduceUsage\ProduceUsageRpt.cs:line 180
  InnerException:
```

### UPDATE 3

Because the exception refers to problems with merged cells, I added this:

```
var pivotData = _xlSheet.Range["A6:D42"];
pivotData.UnMerge();
```

...but it still fails (now with "*PivotFields method of PivotTable class failed Exception Source: Microsoft Office Excel
Exception StackTrace:    at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)*").

**NOTE:** I get "*Do you want to replace the contents of the destination cells in [Book3]Produce Usage by Month?*" (twice) before it fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the specifics of your workbook, it's hard to diagnose some of the issues you list.  The basic means of generating a pivot table would be this:

```
Range sourceData = _xlBook.Worksheets["Produce Usage by Month"].Range["A6:F94"];

PivotCache pc = pch.Create(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, sourceData);
PivotTable pvt = pc.CreatePivotTable(sheet2.Range["A1"], "SummaryPivot");

pvt.PivotFields("Col1").Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
pvt.PivotFields("Col2").Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
pvt.AddDataField(pvt.PivotFields("Col3"), "Sum of Col3", XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum);
```

It looks like your code is not being really explicit about some of the objects.  For example `Produce Usage by Month!A6:F94` means something to Excel (and is probably interpreted by VBA), but I think the interop libraries need more explicit declaration of objects.  In strong typed, this would be what I listed for the `sourceData` object.  `sheet2` is therefore an `Excel.Worksheet` object.

Regarding some of the warnings, such as overwrite warnings, if you change the `DisplayAlerts` property of the Excel application object to false, it will take care of many of these.