# Excel VSTO + C# .NET + Create Pivot Table

Tags: c#, .net, excel, pivot-table, vsto

I'm trying to create a pivot table through C# .Net for an Excel VSTO but keeping getting an exception thrown that states:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

The sheet I am trying to create the pivot table is called oSheet and is the same as the sheet that has the source data

I create a range for the pivot table source:

```
Excel.Range pivotData = osheet.Range["A1", "B3"];
```

A range for where the pivot table will be:

```
Excel.Range pivotDest = osheet.Range["A12", "B14"];
```

then try to create the table with this:

```
osheet.PivotTableWizard(
              Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, 
              pivotData, 
              pivotDest, 
              "Table", 
              true, 
              true, 
              true, 
              true, 
              true, 
              true, 
              false, 
              false, 
              Excel.XlOrder.xlDownThenOver, 
              0, 
              false, 
              false
);
```

The error is occurring in the table wizard line.

Any ideas on what is causing the error or a better way to create a pivot table through C# .Net?

**Full Code**

```
Excel.Application oApp;
Excel.Worksheet osheet;
Excel.Workbook oBook;

oApp = new Excel.Application();
oBook = oApp.Workbooks.Add();
osheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

osheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Name";
osheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Salary";

osheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Frank";
osheet.Cells[2, 2] = 1500000;

osheet.Cells[3, 1] = "Millford";
osheet.Cells[3, 2] = 2200;

//Now capture range of first sheet = I will need this to create pivot table
Excel.Range oRange = osheet.Range["A1", "B3"];


var pch = oBook.PivotCaches();

Excel.Range pivotData = osheet.Range["A1", "B3"];

Excel.PivotCache pc = pch.Create(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, pivotData);
Excel.PivotTable pvt = pc.CreatePivotTable(osheet.Range["A12"], "MyPivotTable");

pvt.PivotFields("Col1").Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
pvt.PivotFields("Col2").Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
pvt.AddDataField(pvt.PivotFields("Col3"), "Sum of Col3", XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use [`PivotTables.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196910.aspx) instead of using wizard?

Answer (score 2):

I just answered a similar question the other day...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39968355/1278553

In a nutshell, the way to create a pivot table in C# is:

```
Excel.Range pivotData = osheet.Range["A1", "B3"];

Excel.PivotCache pc = pch.Create(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, pivotData);
Excel.PivotTable pvt = pc.CreatePivotTable(osheet.Range["A12"], "MyPivotTable");
```

And then assign your row / column and data fields:

```
pvt.PivotFields("Col1").Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
pvt.PivotFields("Col2").Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
pvt.AddDataField(pvt.PivotFields("Col3"), "Sum of Col3", XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum);
```

I plagiarized heavily from my prior answer.

-- EDIT 10/17/2016 --

Per your updated code, this should now work to create the pivot table:

```
var pch = oBook.PivotCaches();

Excel.Range pivotData = osheet.Range["A1", "B3"];

Excel.PivotCache pc = pch.Create(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, pivotData);
Excel.PivotTable pvt = pc.CreatePivotTable(osheet.Range["A12"], "MyPivotTable");

pvt.PivotFields("Name").Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
pvt.AddDataField(pvt.PivotFields("Salary"), "Total Salary",
    Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Hambone; am I missing something obvious in the edited code at the bottom of the answer? A pivot table is not created.

Comment: @HShhanick -- I updated the solution based on the code you posted.  The only real thing wrong was you need to refer to the columns by their name.  I tested this, and it did work on my end.  Hopefully it will on yours as well